# dialogflow - how to get session id?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, sessionid

First of all, I'm a noob with dialogflow and web services.  I'm trying to integrate a dialogflow agent I just created and integrate it with my app on my local computer.  I was able to get project_id and all other important information but no matter where I look, no one seems to talk about where they get session ids from.  Here is the audio-to-text code that I'm using that was forked from api.ai github page:

```
import os
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "My Google Credential"
project_id = 'project id'
session_id = "this i don't know where to get"
audio_file_path = 'my wave file directory name'
language_code = 'en'

def detect_intent_audio(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                        language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with an audio file as input.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversaion."""

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    # Note: hard coding audio_encoding and sample_rate_hertz for simplicity.
    audio_encoding = dialogflow.enums.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16
    sample_rate_hertz = 44100

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
        input_audio = audio_file.read()

    audio_config = dialogflow.types.InputAudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=audio_encoding, language_code=language_code,
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate_hertz)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input,
        input_audio=input_audio)

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))

detect_intent_audio(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                        language_code)
```

I enabled webhook and linked the webhook to heroku, but still I don't see where I can get this session ID.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the link,
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent
, it is stated under the HTTP request session path parameters that 
"It's up to the API caller to choose an appropriate session ID. It can be a random number or some type of user identifier (preferably hashed). The length of the session ID must not exceed 36 bytes."

Comment: I found out later that session id can be any string.  Thank you though!

Comment: Hi, i'm looking for this, i do not want to create a session id but access to the session id from javascript dialogflow V2

Comment: @Gino You can try the following:  exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response }); console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers)); console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body)); var session_id = request.body.session; var session_id_array = session_id.split("/"); session_id = session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1];